# Use golang function inside C-program

Tags: c, go, cgo

I have created a `golang` program to pass some values to `c` program.
[I used this example to do so](https://medium.com/learning-the-go-programming-language/calling-go-functions-from-other-languages-4c7d8bcc69bf)

My simple golang code :

```
package main

import "C"

func Add() int {
        var a = 23
        return a 
 }
func main() {}
```

Then I compiled this using
`go build -o test.so -buildmode=c-shared test.go`

My C code :

```
#include "test.h"

int *http_200 = Add();
```

When I try to compile it using `gcc -o test test.c ./test.so`

I get

> int *http_200 = Add();
>                    ^
>   http_server.c:75:17: error: initializer element is not constant

Why I am getting this error? How to initialize that variable properly in my C code.

PS : edited after first comment.

Comment: The Go function `Add` returns a plain `int` value. In your C code you assign that value to a *pointer* to `int`? And please try to make a [mcve] of the C program, copy-paste the full and complete output of the build, and also tell us how you build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here. First is the incompatibility of the types. Go will return a GoInt. Second issues is that the `Add()` function has to be exported to get the desired header file. If you don't want to change your Go code, then in C you have to use the `GoInt` which is a `long long`.

A complete example is:

**test.go**

```
package main

import "C"

//export Add
func Add() C.int {
    var a = 23
    return C.int(a)
}

func main() {}
```

**test.c**

```
#include "test.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int number = Add();
    printf("%d\n", number);
}
```

Then compile and run:

```
go build -o test.so -buildmode=c-shared test.go
gcc -o test test.c ./test.so &&
./test
```

> 23

---

A second example using the `GoInt`:
**test.go**

```golang
package main

import "C"

//export Add
func Add() int { // returns a GoInt (typedef long long GoInt)
    var a = 23
    return a
}

func main() {}
```

**test.c**

```
#include "test.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long long number = Add();
    printf("%lld\n", number);
}
```

Then compile and run:

```
go build -o test.so -buildmode=c-shared test.go
gcc -o test test.c ./test.so &&
./test
```

> 23

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted to know.